# c# Numericupdown textbox not showing value if i set it to minimum after resetting text

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

This code doesn't work if i set the value of the textbox to 1, with a minimum of 1.

```
numStartChannel.Minimum = 1;
numStartChannel.ResetText();
numStartChannel.Value = 1;
```

The control actually has the correct value internally, but still displays blank on the form.  Note that the reset is actually ran in a click event, not directly before the value setting.

This code DOES work, but I don't know why.
numStartChannel.Minimum = 1;
numStartChannel.ResetText();
numStartChannel.Value = 2;
numStartChannel.Value = 1;

And finally, this code doesn't work:

```
numStartChannel.Minimum = 1;
numStartChannel.ResetText();
numStartChannel.Value = 1;
numStartChannel.Value = 1;
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?  C# Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Framework or Core project? WimForms controls and designer are still a bit wonky in Core; likely bug. I'd test it in Framework 4.8 to be sure.

Comment: Why are you calling `ResetText()`? `numStartChannel.Minimum = 1; numStartChannel.Value = 1;` is enough. The `Text` is irrelevant, what matters in a NUD is the `Value`. Describe a little better the context of this operation and post some code that can reproduce the issue. E.g., is databindings involved? Did you bind the `Text` property?

Comment: Getting NUD to misbehave is not that difficult, it is one of the controls done by the B-team.  It should have overridden ResetText() to ensure the NUD always displays a value, but that didn't happen.  The fix is simple, just don't call it since assigning Value already resets the text.

Comment: [NumericUpDown.Text](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NumericUpDown.cs,0aaedcc47a6cf725) property is a useless property and that's why the property have been hidden in code editor and in property grid. Also [ResetText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resettext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method; it belongs to the Control base class as is really not intended to do any special thing but resetting the text at design-time or run-time to the default value which is empty.

Comment: You should always set the `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Value` and they will take care of the `Text`  as well. You don't need to call `ResetText` or set the `Text` of the control.

Comment: but i did.  I am using the control to input the starting channel of a channel range for pixel lights.  If you click a category in my treeview, or an entry we haven't saved yet, the data entry fields must appear to be blank so as to not confuse the user.  And i've heard back from users.  It's confusing them.

Comment: NumericUpDown control Value doesn't support null. Then what's the question exactly?

Comment: Not trying to store null.  I have a solution anyway.  The problem was caused by clearing the text display which doesn't clear the value so when i reassigned the exact same value, it didn't redraw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that if you clear the text of the control, it doesn't clear the value.  Therefore when i was trying to set the value back into it again to display, it wasn't triggering the control to know the value had been updated, because it hadn't.  The unfortunate solution is to also set the .Text value to anything non-empty such as a space.  Note: intellisense claims there is no such property but there is.  Setting the value afterwards causes the control to redraw properly.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried your code with the same result.

When I remove the `numStartChannel.ResetText();` it works for me.

```
        numStartChannel.Minimum = 1;
        numStartChannel.Value = 2;
```

My Explination is that the `resetText()` sets the text to the default. Which is '0'. That is below your minium.

Thats works for me too:

```
        numStartChannel.Minimum = 0;
        numStartChannel.ResetText();
        numStartChannel.Value = 1;
```

If you use `numStartChannel.Value++;` after the reset the Value is displayed correctly.

I have currently no clue why the text is not updated after reseting the text. I think that it might be a bug in the control it self.

Why do you need to use `resetText`? Setting the value changes the Text.

*Used .NET Framework: 4.7.2*

Comment: is there a way to clear the text in the control?  I was using resettext to make it blank.

Comment: Got the solution.  ResetText is just clearing the text but leaves the value in the control.  Trying to set the exact same value to it again simply didn't trigger the control because the value didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I've never personally regarded the *Text* property on an NUD as useful from the code's perspective in any way; it's much more logical to just use *Value*

You want to reset an NUD to Minimum?

```
NUD.Value = NUD.Minimum;
```

Avoid using Text; if you want numeric strings, you can string the value yourself:

```
NUD.Value.ToString("F3"); //eg "123.457" if Value is 123.456789
```

Comment: i wasn't trying to set it to minimum.  The value i was setting it to was coincidentally minimum.  The first device I save settings for is going to start at channel 1.

Comment: Bind the NUD's Value property to the application settings